# Add UILabel Or Words on top of a rectangle in drawRect

Tags: ios, string, uiview, drawrect

Hello i have an custom view with override drawRect method, used to draw the bars of a graph and the code is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:39.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, barColor.CGColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);

    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

How i can draw an String on the top of the bar? I want decrease the height of rect and in the top of the rectangle(with the decreased height) draw de string with white color (different color than the used color for the bars).

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPoint textPoint = CGPointMake((rect.size.width - textSize.width) / 2, 0);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, textPoint.x, textPoint.y, text, strlen(text));
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFillStroke);
```

Calculate textSize by

```
textSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
```

Comment: not working because i think that i'm make an wrong manage of context stack. I think that the text has the same color of background and so its impossible to read.